# Prevent recompilation by not updating timestamps for identical files

Tags: gcc, makefile, gfortran

In my projects it often happens that files are unnecessarily recompiled, similar to the problem described [here](http://lagrange.mechse.illinois.edu/f90_mod_deps/). A simple Fortran example would be that `a.o` depends on `b.mod`, which depends on `c.mod`. If a comment in the source file for `c.mod` is changed, all files will be recompiled, even though they do not change.

A solution would be to not update the timestamp on files that are identical after compilation (for example, because it was just a comment that changed). My question is whether this is possible with e.g. `gcc`, or if there are alternative ways to solve this problem using GNU `make`.

Comment: The web page you cite explains that `gfortran` version 4.3.0 does not update `c.mod` if its content does not change. Why do you not use this version or a more recent one? And, if you do, why exactly doesn't it solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I should have read that page more carefully (I was just looking for an example). I'll update the post when I find out whether this solves the problem.